# smooth transition of background color / vue js

Tags: css, vue.js, background-color

I am trying to smooth transition between background linear gradients in vue js

Previously when I created this transition effect using plain js / HTML / css - i created a div for each color and just changed there opacity - fading one out to another

(you can see the effect i am trying to create here, just nav between different languages to see the effect) https://littleleo.dev/

in vue js -

the nav invokes a function when clicked (which gets the nav id)

```
<Navbar :articleData="articleData" @backgroundColor="background"/>
```

background(f) updates a watched property - using a list of colors

```
methods: {
    background(id){
        let bg_id = id-1 // -1 so the number is inline with the array starting at 0 not 1
        this.backgroundColor = this.backgrounds[bg_id]
    }



data(){return{

backgroundColor: null,

backgrounds: 
      [
      'linear-gradient(45deg, #e96443, #904e95)', 
      'linear-gradient(45deg, #3a7bd5, #3a6073)', 
      'linear-gradient(45deg, #f7ff00, #db36a4)',
      
      'linear-gradient(45deg, #B24592, #F15F79)',
      'linear-gradient(45deg, #FFB75E, #ED8F03)',
      'linear-gradient(45deg, #673AB7, #512DA8)',

      'linear-gradient(45deg, #fc00ff, #00dbde)',
      'linear-gradient(45deg, #00C9FF, #92FE9D)',
      ],
```

and the magic happens here: where the background is changed

```
// changes background color 
  watch: {
    backgroundColor: function(){
      document.querySelector('.topElements').style.background = this.backgroundColor
    }
  }
```

So currently this happens with no transition time between the background colors changing - i was wondering if anyone knew how to transition without creating a overlay div for each of the colors &/or there is some clever vue js magic that can solve this type of issue:

further details:

this is in App.vue and my template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="topElements" :class="[noneSelected]"> // <<< COLOR APPLIED HERE
      <!-- animation -->
      <lottie :options="defaultOptions" :height="350" :width="350"/>
      <Navbar :articleData="articleData" @backgroundColor="background"/>

      <span class="breaker"></span>
      <transition name="content-holder">
        <router-view :key="$route.path"/>
      </transition>
    </div>
      <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

the background color is being applied to everything inside of the class="topElements"

---

any help or suggestions would be amazing -
thanks in advance -
Wally

Answer (score 0):

As vue.js documentation says, the best way to make a similar effect is using absolute positioning.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes
This is the best way to deal with it.

Most tricks wich get the same effect has a much bigger code and it is not the right way.

To understand how vue.js transition works please visit https://alligator.io/vuejs/understanding-transitions/
https://medium.com/@msanathkumar/understanding-transitions-and-animations-in-vuejs-115a0f5c6fbc